# Fit content width-wise in pdf

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

When rendering to pdf, I need the html page to be 100% of the print width. Otherwise content gets cut off. Is there an easy way to do this?

I came up with a work-around, which gets the html width after rendering and then sets the zoom factor to force the correct width.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    dpi = 89.9, // strange, but that's what I get on Mac
    pageWidth = 210; // in mm

var getWidth = function() {
    return page.evaluate(function() {
        // get width manually
        // ...
        return width;
    });
};

page.paperSize = {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait'};

page.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.zoomFactor = (pageWidth / 25.4) * dpi / getWidth();
        page.render(system.args[2]);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 200);
});
```

Looking for a straight forward solution, because getting the width requires me to do some tricks due to the framework I use.

Comment: I've used the same solution, haven't been able to find an alternative. I'm using windows and have had to hardcode the dpi to 120. I've tried various methods to obtain the DPI however the DPI returned by them does not work e.g. GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hDC, int nIndex) returned 96.

Comment: Yeah had the same thing. I'm actually using a dpi of 89.9 on Linux to fill the page without a margin.

Answer (score 7):

Managed to solve this by adding the following CSS rule which will zoom out the page and make it fit:

```
 html {
    zoom: 0.60; 
  }
```

Comment: this works well for everything else except css borders.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `rasterize.js` as follows.

Make a backup of rasterize.js

Remove this block (approx. line 18-31)

```
if (system.args.length > 4) {
    page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
}
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Replace it with this code block

```
 if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = parseFloat(system.args[4].split("=")[1]);
 }
 page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
console.log("zoomFactor: " + page.zoomFactor);
      page.evaluate(function(zoom) {
        return document.querySelector('body').style.zoom = zoom;
    }, page.zoomFactor); // <-- your zoom here
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });
```

Then you can export html to pdf on-the-fly like this:

```
~/bin/phantomjs ~/bin/phantomjs/examples/rasterize.js \ 
'http://example.com/index.html' \ 
mysite.pdf paperformat=A4 zoom=0.4
```