# how to set dpi using phantomjs node?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs node module. below is the link where from i get this module.

https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node

this really work nice when i create a jpg image file from html. but its default "dpi" is 72 which is not good for printing the image file. so i want to set the dpi when i rendering the image.

from the above link i read some example like page.set('viewportSize', {width:640,height:480}). its set the image size perfectly. but i want to set dpi of image please guide me how can i achieve this.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open("http://www.google.com", function (status) {
       page.render("bla.jpg");
        ph.exit();

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. There's an unmerged PR though, if you fancy hacking around on some C++ you might be able to do it: https://github.com/1st1/phantomjs/commit/de90d0712f20dd7a68eb5ac5b302e535ced5a7f4

Comment: thanks Matt  sir for your replay. i try this before posting the question here. but i face another problem when i done this. i tell you how i did this. i simply get the clone


sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9

make some change where dpi hardcoded value is 72 to 300 and builds the project by using 

./build.sh
after 100% building when i start process again i get a message phantomjs is not installed.

Comment: here is the link where from i get resources 

http://phantomjs.org/build.html

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways.

### 1. Zoom

You can use [`page.zoomFactor`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/zoom-factor.html) to zoom the page. You have to increase the [viewport size](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) accordingly before changing the zoomFactor:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 1600, height: 800 };
page.zoomFactor = 300.0/72.0;
page.render("zoom4.jpg");
```

## 2. PDF

If you are concerned with the quality, then render a pdf of the page. A pdf is vector-based and you can zoom in as much as you like. It works by using the `pdf` extension when you give the filename to `render`:

```
page.render("bla.pdf");
```

You can see how the [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) example deals with the page sizes. There are some caveats though. You have to keep in mind to adjust the width of the rendered pdf. See for example this (unanswered) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21086398/1816580).

Comment: acutely the problem is not zooming. let me explain my problem. in my html i set hardcode width=600 px & height=412 px. so when i created image its give me the image in width =8.34 incs  and height=5.72 inches because ( imageWidth= htmlWidth/72 & imageHeight= htmlHeight/72)  so imageWidth= 600/70= 8.333 and imageHeight= 412/72 =5.72 inches. but if dpi is 300 than result is IW=600/300=2 & IH=412/300=1.37 inches approx. this is the size what is want but don't get. hope u understand what i wan to say! please help i need it

Comment: Yes, then zoom the page to `300.0/72` and you will get your 300dpi jpg. The dpi/ppi information inside of the jpg will not change, because you can't set the dpi in phantomjs. You will need to set the correct dpi in photoshop or whatever image manipulation tool you use.

Comment: again its not working. when i use this logic. image size increased.

i used this according to  me in all possible  way like

var dpi=300.0/72.0;
dpi=dpi.toFixed(2);
1st way
page.set('viewportSize ',{ width: 1600, height: 800 });
page.set('zoomFactor ',dpi);

2nd way
page.viewportSize={ width: 1600, height: 800 };
page.zoomFactor=dpi;

3rd way
var obj={'viewportSize':{ width: 1600, height: 800 },'zoomFactor':dpi};
page.set(obj);

but yet not works. totally  fedup :(

Comment: What do you mean with *it's not working*? A webpage has no notion of used space in the real world, so dpi are inherently arbitrary and will depend on a lot of factors. As you see, in the linked request in the comments, that OSX simply says `72` and windows `96`. It's just a value that you have to work with. So saying that you need 300 dpi is just as arbitrary and has no real world connection (printer is a real world object). If you want to print the webpage, then render as pdf and see if it looks right. When you then print the pdf you will probably have some kind of adjustment option for dpi.1

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to not use the in phantom pdf rendering process, because the quality of the generated pdfs is unacceptably bad.

First I generate the image at whatever resolution I need for the required dpi. For me this was 3300x2550 (11in x 8.5in at 300dpi) and used a page zoom factor of 2.364 (closest approximation of a divisor of 11 because we use 11pt font to 2550/1080; 26/11) to keep the same approximate font size as on 1080p. Then I use an external utility (iText or Aspose for example) to push the generated image into a pdf. It prints beautifully and looks good in the pdf. The only problem I have is the storage space is somewhat substantial because a 3300x2550 image file is generated on each run.

Comment: Can you please share some details regarding any issue you are facing while using Aspose as I am unable to understand the last line in your above comments. May be I can try helping you out while using Aspose to accomplish your desired results.

Comment: The pdf ends up being much larger with the images rather than just being rendered with vectors as it normally is. It goes from being maybe a few dozen kb to 5-10 megabytes. Not a huge concern, as I said, but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the -1. I'm glad you could comment as to why it didn't work.